# Error in php mailer in php

Tags: php, email

I have been created, simple php code for sending email.

Here is the code:

index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

error shows like this:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message could not be sent.
>
> Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

May i know, what i am missing, how can i fix this error.

Thanks.,

Here is the code for [php mailer](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:5189)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error handling with PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386544/error-handling-with-phpmailer)

Comment: according your link , i just confused, where i can add code and fix.. help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check `php.ini` file and verify that `openssl.dll` is uncommented .

**EDIT:**
`$mail->Host = "localhost";`  // This must be the **smtp server**

Also you need to include the below configurations

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = your port number;
```

**NOTE:**

Always initiate PHPMailer sending in the parameter  `true` , because it helps you to catch the exceptions.

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
 //set all the configurations
  $mailer->Send();//send  mail
  echo "Message Sent";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

checkout the github link for usage [phpmailer github link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: checkout the edit... $mail->Host cannot be localhost, it must be a smtp server name

Comment: check the edited answer ....also checkout the github example of its usage, it might help you

Comment: Your code is wrong.....it will never work  $mail->Host cannot be localhost you can use $mail->Host ="smtp.gmail.com" and provide any gmail address and password and try

Comment: you are getting that error because $mail is not being recognized as an object. try printing it and see what you get, try print_r($mail) after you initialize the phpmailer

Comment: Did you get the object when you tried to print it? I think the object is not being created may be because you did not include the phpmailer's class path properly