# SMTP connect() failed error on localhost

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

I have just started coding in PHP. I'm trying to send a mail but it throws an error **Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.**

Below is the code i am using :

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname('ssl://smtp.gmail.com'); 

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';  
    $mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '********';   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
    $mail->Port = 587;  

    $mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com','Abc') ;
    $mail->addReplyTo('abc@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress("abc@gmail.com",'No REPLY');
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = "12345";
    $mail->Subject = "<b>OTP for password reset<b>";
    $mail->Body = "Hi! Your OTP is : ";

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
       echo 'Message was not sent.';
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       } 
    else {
       echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which php version is this ?

Comment: check this: [Error handling with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386544/error-handling-with-phpmailer)

Comment: PHP version is 5.6.25

Comment: i have changed the code to $mail = new PHPMailer(true);Now i have the following error :
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting' in C:\wamp64\www\cpms\class.phpmailer.php on line 1541

Comment: How to fix this issue on ampps using with Mac OS ?

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('ssl://smtp.gmail.com');
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
$mail->Port = 587;
```

to

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  
$mail->Port = 465;
```

And check for `open_ssl` enabled

**Open your `php.ini` and search for this line
`;extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semi colon before it , save the file and restart your webserver.**

Comment: The open_ssl in PHP.INI  is already enabled.
I had the code used before but still got the same error.
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";

Comment: SMTP connect() failed

Comment: set $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

Comment: Worked for me. Big Thanks!!