# PHPMailer works in my home pc with mamp in local, does not work in the work pc always with mamp in local

Tags: php, phpmailer, mamp

Hello guys I have a small problem I'm developing a contact form that send data by email, working at home with mamp, works great but when I copy the whole folder in htdocs and report it in the work pc always locally and always with MAMP , nothing works, at home I have a mac at work I'm in windows, can I change some properties?

Test carried out also from the pc of the work I connect with teamviewer to the home pc and it works perfectly, only here it does not work but is it possible?

Comment: PHPMailer falls back on PHPMail if it goes wrong.  It's possible that its using PHPMail on your home PC, but then its not available (maybe) on your work machine.  Do you have code examples?  Log files?  What have you tried?  Your question is a bit broad

Comment: see me caught unprepared on this because it is the first time that happens to me, I do not even know what to answer, you can give me guidelines in order to do step by step together, what is needed?

Comment: Have a read of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386544/error-handling-with-phpmailer about PHPMailer error reporting.  Then report back here with your errors, or examples of the code your are using

Comment: Most likely a connectivity or local config problem on your work PC, nothing to do with your script.