# How to verify that an email is sent with PHPMailer in AWS EC2 instance running the LAMP stack?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I got the server from my client and this is the first time I using Amazon EC2 server I install Apache, MySQL and PHP inside the server and the client install the Amazon SES mail server and they send me the access-key and secret-key to me. For the email configuration, I install composer, aws-sdk-php and PHPMailer using that I include the key's what they send to me to my code. I try to send an email with my site contact-us form but I didn't receive the emails. Please attached my code below. Please check and advise me where I made a mistake in my code.

Note : I install the plugin inside my var/www/html folder.

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

// Create an SesClient. Change the value of the region parameter if you're
// using an AWS Region other than US West (Oregon). Change the value of the
// profile parameter if you want to use a profile in your credentials file
// other than the default.
$SesClient = new SesClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'key' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx'
]);

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
$sender_email = 'no-reply@demo.com';

// Replace these sample addresses with the addresses of your recipients. If
// your account is still in the sandbox, these addresses must be verified.
$recipient_emails = ['demo@gmail.com','demo123@gmail.com'];

// Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
// set, comment the following variable, and the
// 'ConfigurationSetName' => $configuration_set argument below.
$configuration_set = 'ConfigSet';

$subject = 'Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)';
$plaintext_body = 'This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.' ;
$html_body =  '<h1>AWS Amazon Simple Email Service Test Email</h1>'.
    '<p>This email was sent with <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses/">'.
    'Amazon SES</a> using the <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/">'.
    'AWS SDK for PHP</a>.</p>';
$char_set = 'UTF-8';

try {
    $result = $SesClient->sendEmail([
        'Destination' => [
            'ToAddresses' => $recipient_emails,
        ],
        'ReplyToAddresses' => [$sender_email],
        'Source' => $sender_email,
        'Message' => [
            'Body' => [
                'Html' => [
                    'Charset' => $char_set,
                    'Data' => $html_body,
                ],
                'Text' => [
                    'Charset' => $char_set,
                    'Data' => $plaintext_body,
                ],
            ],
            'Subject' => [
                'Charset' => $char_set,
                'Data' => $subject,
            ],
        ],
        // If you aren't using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        // following line
        'ConfigurationSetName' => $configuration_set,
    ]);
    $messageId = $result['MessageId'];
    echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ".$e->getAwsErrorMessage()."\n");
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

1) Verify your email address with AWS SES. You have to verify that you own the email address.

2) Confirm your SMTP credentials, these are ***not*** the same as your AWS credentials.
-- SMTP credentials are found on this page (after you have logged in to your AWS account): https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?#smtp-settings

3) To confirm that PHP is working, please run `php -v` in your EC2 terminal to confirm that you get the PHP version printed on-screen.

4) When all of this is working, confirm that you have PHPMailer correctly installed (`require './vendor/autoload.php';`, replace the path with the one you have on your system)

5) If your AWS EC2 instance is in a region other than US West, declare and assign values to the `$host` and `$port` values.

6) Still not working? What error message are you getting from PHPMailer? Please see the following guide for error handling with PHPMailer: [Error handling with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386544/error-handling-with-phpmailer)

Comment: I submitting the form with ajax but I'm getting any message from this I don't know why to help me out of these issues.