# PHPMailer constantly failing to send email

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I've been working on a login system and keep running into errors when trying to send e-mails over PHPMailer, can't get any better in-site into the errors so any help?

Function that doesn't work:

```php
function SendUserConfirmationEmail(&$formvars)
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    
    $mailer->AddAddress($formvars['email'],$formvars['name']);
    
    $mailer->Subject = "Your registration with ".$this->sitename;

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        
    
    $confirmcode = $formvars['confirmcode'];
    
    $confirm_url = $this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder().'/confirmreg.php?code='.$confirmcode;
    
    $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$formvars['name']."\r\n\r\n".
    "Thanks for your registration with ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Please click the link below to confirm your registration.\r\n".
    "$confirm_url\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    "Regards,\r\n".
    "Webmaster\r\n".
    $this->sitename;

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        $mailer->ErrorInfo;
        $this->HandleError("Failed sending registration confirmation email.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry for no activity, I had to make myself a autoloader and request the class.phpmailer file as require_once!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The one I have in HandleError, "Failed sending registration confirmation email."

Comment: That's the notice you created when something failed, can I get the actual error message please? You can read about capturing errors here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386544/error-handling-with-phpmailer`

Comment: Ah yep! Sorry bout that, using "echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo;", gives me a: "Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function. "

Comment: Are you including the library correctly? Did you install with composer? if not, did you include: <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';